# WP-Photo gallery in right sidebar

Tags: wordpress, gallery, nextgen-gallery

I am new to Wordpress, I have one website running on Wordpress. I want to create photo gallery for my website . I did R&D and found NextGEN Gallery helpful for my requirement.but not exactly.

i want to build gallery as like this one : http://www.deccanherald.com/ here you can find one photo gallery on right sidebar.

NextGen gallery sidebar widget allows photos as slideshow not whole gallery/album

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the website and found that the site is using [SlideJS](http://www.slidesjs.com/) for right sidebar slider.

You need to create one widget for that and integrate the code inside the widget for the slider from the given link.

Comment: Yes i got it sir! I will try to built one widget same like that.. Thank you very much for your time!